# Can i simplify the printing of the contents of multiple arrays using a switch? C#

Tags: c#

I want to be able to change the array that is printed by the foreach loop by using a switch statement however the only way I found to do this is by using 5 foreach loops. I want to be able to use one to simplify my code and make it easier to add new arrays is this possible?

```
switch (arraychoice.Key)
{
  case ConsoleKey.A:
    Console.Clear();
    bubblesort.Bubblesort(dataset.Num128_change);

    foreach (double item in dataset.Num128_change)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
    break;

    case ConsoleKey.B:
    Console.Clear();
    bubblesort.Bubblesort(dataset.Num128_close);

    foreach (double item in dataset.Num128_close)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
    break;

 case ConsoleKey.C:
    Console.Clear();
    bubblesort.Bubblesort(dataset.Num128_high);

    foreach (double item in dataset.Num128_close)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    break;

 case ConsoleKey.D:
    Console.Clear();
    bubblesort.Bubblesort(dataset.Num128_low);

    foreach (double item in dataset.Num128_close)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    break;

 case ConsoleKey.E:
    Console.Clear();
    bubblesort.Bubblesort(dataset.Num128_open);

    foreach (double item in dataset.Num128_close)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    break;
}
```

}

Comment: There are a lot of ways to simplify, but for a start can we create a function?

Comment: For three of the options, the array you're sorting isn't the array you're printing. Is that deliberate?

Comment: @DaisyShipton Yeah that's an error thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of variables like a box.  You declare your variable/box and decide what 'type' of data goes into it.

You can then use that variable with one chunk of code, regardless of what actual data went into the variable (or box).

So where you have several arrays of `double` type data: `dataset.Num128_change`, `dataset.Num128_close`, you can put one of those arrays into a variable (`chosenArray`) before working on it.

Eg. this isn't as succinct as other answer(s) but I think it is clearer for you.

```
double[] chosenArray = double[0];
switch (arraychoice.Key)
{
  case ConsoleKey.A:
    chosenArray = dataset.Num128_change;
    break;
  case ConsoleKey.B:
    chosenArray = dataset.Num128_close;
    break;

  //add the other cases
  ....
}

bubblesort.Bubblesort(chosenArray);
foreach (double item in chosenArray)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help this was the most elegant solution and worked well with the current arrangements of my program

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about types in your program, but I would think about something like this, at this point (pseudocode) :

```
//init map of relation between the key pressed and sort order to execute
var map = new Dictionary<Console.Key, SortType> { 
             {ConsoleKey.A, dataset.Num128_change},
             {ConsoleKey.B, dataset.Num128_close},
             {ConsoleKey.C, dataset.Num128_high}  
}

.. after somewhere in the code  

Console.Clear();
bubblesort.Bubblesort(map[arraychoice.Key]);
foreach (var item in dataset) //iterator over results
        Console.WriteLine(item); //`ToString()` invocation on type
```

It's not a "copy/paste" solution, but hopefully you got the point.

Comment: `dataset = map[arraychoice.Key]` in the foreach?

Comment: @JimW: `map[arraychoice.Key]` returns a sort order

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the point of trying to simplify your code.

Your five loops aren't gonna execute at the same time, not even one after the other, but only when the condition hits.

Trying to simplify this will cause your application to use more resource hence using come sort of list and indexing on it.

Anyway, you can put your loop in a function and call it.

```
switch (arraychoice.Key)
{
    case ConsoleKey.A:
         Console.Clear();
         bubblesort.Bubblesort(dataset.Num128_close);
         theloop(dataset.Num128_change);
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.B:
        Console.Clear();
        bubblesort.Bubblesort(dataset.Num128_close);
        theloop(dataset.Num128_change);
        break;
    default: 
        break;
}

void theloop<T>(IEnumerable<T> List )
{
    foreach (var item in List)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

This uses a single loop if you understand what happens when you call a function.